# How can I override the Jekyll build command to set some config options only when building?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm using [Jekyll Asset Pipeline](https://github.com/matthodan/jekyll-asset-pipeline) to build my website and I'd like to only compress the website (which takes about 20 seconds) when I'm publishing it. To do this I have to enable these values programmatically in the config file:

```
asset_pipeline:
  bundle: false
  compress: false
```

I've tried to code a plugin but it isn't working. Could someone help me as to why?

```
module Jekyll
    module Commands
        # I overwrite this here so we only do heavy work (like compressing HTML and stuff)
        # when we are building the site, not when testing (which uses jekyll serve)
        class << Build
            alias_method :_process, :process
            def process(options)
                require 'jekyll-press'
                options['asset_pipeline']['bundle'] = true
                options['asset_pipeline']['compress'] = true
                _process(options)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even need a special gem - you can pass multiple configuration files to `jekyll build`:

First, the regular config file, with all the settings that are always needed, plus the values to disable compressing, since you don't always want it to run each time you're building locally:

#### _config.yml:

```
destination: _site
source: src
markdown: rdiscount
# ... and many more settings that are always needed

asset_pipeline:
  bundle: false
  compress: false
```

Then, you need a second config file for publishing which overrides only the values that you actually want to be different:

#### _config-publish.yml:

```
asset_pipeline:
  bundle: true
  compress: true
```

---

So when you're not publishing, you just run `jekyll build` like before.

But when you're publishing, you pass **both** config files in the right order:

```
jekyll build --config _config.yml,_config-publish.yml
```

Jekyll will apply them in the order you passed them, so the settings in the second file will overwrite the ones in the first file, and `bundle` and `compress` will be set to `true` in the end.

---

In case you can't control what parameters will be passed to `jekyll build` *(maybe on GitHub Pages? I never used it, but maybe...)* you can do the same thing, just the other way round:

- Set `bundle` and `compress` to `true` in the default config file
- Whenever you're **not** publishing, use a second `_config-dev.yml` file to set `bundle` and `compress` to `false` again

Answer (score 1):

The `gueard-jekyll-plus` gem allows you to configure multiple configuration files where the later ones override the former ones. I have the same set up where I have a `_development.yml` file that turns off all the asset compilation settings for development work. Yes you have to set guard up, but it makes it simple to refresh the site. Here's the relevant section:

```
guard 'jekyll-plus', extensions: %w[slim yml scss js md html xml txt rb], serve: true,    rack_config: 'config.ru', config: ['_config.yml', '_development.yml'] do
  watch /.*/
  ignore /^build/
end
```

I detail most of the basic setup in of the Gem in the article [Integrate Jekyll with Slim, Zurb Foundation, Compass and an Asset Pipeline](http://www.neverstopbuilding.com/jekyll-slim-compass-blog?utm_source=stack&medium=direct&utm_campaign=jekyll-slim-compass-blog).

Couldn't you also just do:

```
> jekyll build --config _development.yml
```

To build with a different configuration file?